# I want to find differential of spherical besssel function at r=0

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I want to find an differential of a spherical Bessel function at r=0.
This is my reduced radial wave wavefunction.

```
u(r) = c*r*SphericalBesselJ[0, (b*r)/L]
```

c,b are constants and r is from 0 to L (L = 50)

```
R(r) = u(r)/ r
```

I want to find the value of R'(r) at 0

```
|R'(0)|^2
```

I encounter 1/0 term in the answer and i dont know if there is a way to overcome this.

Comment: You must define functions like `u[r_] = c*r*...`. Please read an introduction to Mathematica's syntax. Concretely, [The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 $Version
 (*"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"*)

 ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"];

u[r_] = c*r*SphericalBesselJ[0, (b*r)/L];
R[r_] = u[r]/r;
Lim[r_] := Abs[D[R[r], r]]^2; 
Limit[Lim[r], r -> 0, GenerateConditions -> True]

(*0*)

Limit[Lim[r], r -> 0, Assumptions -> {c != 0, b > 0, L > 0}]

(*0*)
```

**EDITED: 4.4.2022**

```
 w = Table[i, {i, 1, 8}];
 p = Table[i, {i, 1, 100}];
 L = 50; 
 as = Table[BesselJZero[3/2, i], {i, Length[p]}];
 urS = Table[Sum[(as[[n]] r)/L*SphericalBesselJ[0, (as[[n]] r)/L], {n,Length[p]}], {i, Length[w]}]; 
 RS1[r_] = urS[[1]]/r;
 ur0[r_] := Abs[D[RS1[r], r]]^2;
 Limit[ur0[r], r -> 0]
 (*0*)
```

Computing numerically:

```
 $MaxExtraPrecision = 100; M = 30; N[ur0[r] /. {r -> 10^-M}, M]

  (*4.62586941218184559841353356175*10^-54*)
```

Comment: It should be noticed that `u[r_] = c*r*SphericalBesselJ[0, (b*r)/L];
R[r_] = u[r]/r;
Lim[r_] := D[R[r], r];
Limit[Lim[r], r -> 0, GenerateConditions -> True]` performs `ConditionalExpression[Indeterminate, c != 0]` whereas `L = 1; c = 1; b = 1;Plot[Evaluate[D[R[r], r]], {r, -8, 8}]` shows the continuity at the origin.

Comment: Ok  i have been trying to use your idea (Thank you for help) and i am not able to work it out. so here is my original code that i want to address. `w = Table[i, {i, 1, 8}];
p = Table[i, {i, 1, 100}];
L = 50;
as = Table[N[BesselJZero[3/2, i]], {i, Length[p]}]; 
urS = Table[
   Sum[(as[[n]] r)/L*SphericalBesselJ[0, (as[[n]] r)/L], {n, 
     Length[p]}], {i, Length[w]}];
RS1[r_] = urS[[1]]/r
ur0[r_] := Abs[D[RS1[r], r]]^2
Limit = [ur0[r], r -> 0, GenerateConditions -> True]`

Comment: @AnshulBokade. I edited  my answer.

Comment: Oh man. thank you. thank you very much